# div layout - four boxes with text underneath

Tags: html

I have the following code :

```
#pageMainContent {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.pageMainContentLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.pageMainContentRight {
    width: 600px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 90px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.pageMainContentRight a{
    color:#000000;
```

and code :

```
 <div id="pageMainContent">

                       <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:200px; padding-top:50px"><img alt="" src="image1.png" /></div>
                        <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%;"><p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span></p>More Text.</div><br />

                        <div style="clear:both"></div>

                        <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:160px; padding-top:40px"><img alt="" src="image2.png" /></div>
                        <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%;"><p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span></p>More Text.</div><br />

                        <div style="clear:both"></div><br />

                        <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:150px; padding-top:30px"><img alt="" src="image3.png" /></div>
                        <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%; text-align:justify;"><p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span></p>More Text.</div><br />

                        <div style="clear:both"></div>

                        <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:160px; padding-top:34px"><img alt="" src="image4.png" /></div>
                        <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%; margin-top:-20px"><p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span></p>Text </span></p>More Text.</div><br />

                    </div>
```

Inside the div pageMainContent I want to display 4 pictures with text underneath (in the shape of a box).  What is the correct layout in each of the four divs ?

(its left picture then text underneath then horiztonal to that picture its right picture with text underneath - drop a few spaces and repeat for 2 more boxes)

```
P-----------------------P
T-----------------------T

P-----------------------P
T-----------------------T
```

P - Picture
T - Text

Comment: do you want all four blocks of images in same row?

Comment: yes - so they match up horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you had was that you mixed up which things should be left content and right content. I made a very basic method of making a box. You can format it as you wish

```
  <div class="pageMainContentLeft">
     <img alt="image1" src="image1.png" />
  </div>  
  <div class="pageMainContentRight">
     <img alt="Image2" src="image2.png" />
 </div>


  <div style="clear:both"></div><br />

 <div class="pageMainContentLeft"><p>text</div>
 <div class="pageMainContentRight"><p>text</p></div>


     <div style="clear:both"></div><br />


  <div class="pageMainContentLeft">
     <img alt="image3" src="image3.png" />
  </div>  
  <div class="pageMainContentRight">
    <img alt="Image4" src="image4.png" />
  </div>


           <div style="clear:both"></div><br />

   <div class="pageMainContentLeft"><p>text</div>
   <div class="pageMainContentRight"><p>text</p></div>

 <style>

#pageMainContent {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.pageMainContentLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.pageMainContentRight {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}

</style>
```

Comment: ive got picture, picture, text, text, picture, picture, text ,text  and they are all left sided

Comment: its the positional layout that I am having trouble with.  I wanted one picture on the left and one on the right with text underneath and then repeat the process for 2 more pictures

Comment: When I run my code I get the box though. Did you make sure to use the CSS?

Comment: thats more like it !! yes its the right shape.. the only thing is how to narrow the four from the edge, can you make them closer together ?

Comment: By adjusting the individual styles.  In the left class put margin-left:something, and in the right class put margin-right:something

The rest is up to you to style as you wish

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:200px; padding-top:50px">
<img alt="" src="image1.png" />
<div style="width:100px;"><p>Text Here</p></div>
</div>
```

Also do something similar for the right div. I however recommend you restructure your code to make things easier for you.

Comment: are they not all on top of each other ?

Comment: i can increase the width to seperate them but how do i drop two of them down  underneath the first two ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i have to delete this comment and suggest something different as i had read your question wrong.

Comment: its ok.  but its the positional layout that I am having problems with.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="sectionContainer">

  <div class="entry" >
        <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:200px; padding-top:50px">
            <img alt="" src="img/inspire/1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%;">
                <p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span>
                </p>More Text.
        </div>

  </div>


                    <div class="entry">
                    <div class="pageMainContentLeft" style="width:100px; height:200px; padding-top:50px">
                        <img alt="" src="img/inspire/1.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="pageMainContentRight" style="font-size:16px; line-height:130%;">
                        <p><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:600; font-family:Arial;">Text </span>
                        </p>More Text.
                    </div>
                    </div>

</div>
```

If you divide you code into sections, you will have more control of the code.

In my code, divs with sectionContainer class will display as rows because you will not define any floating for it in you css. So by definition, div elements are block elements and they will show as blocks, that is one on top of another.

For class entry, define a float to the left in your css and they will all be aligned from the left.

Make sure the width of .sectionContainer class is wide enough to accommodate two .entry items.

Comment: i got a working version but its still a bit blocky.  For example I would like more control over the text under the pictures - I would like to have it centered, use the full width of the picture and change font twice.